# Android Studio "com.android.tools.build.gradle 7.1.0" error

Tags: android, flutter

I am using Android Studio for flutter development but in my office environment in build mode. I am facing this issue:

[image]

Things already that i already tried:

- already added certificate in carcets in androidstudio/jre/security
- whitelisted the URLs. i.e if i hit this url in the browser I'm able to download Pom File
- added google() in the repositories { } block.

Answer (score 0):

As of this date, and Android Studio Electric Eel: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2` is the one of the latest AGP supported

Comment: Hi I am currently using Android Studio ChipMunk 2021.2.1 patch 2

Comment: Then open File > Project Structure > Project. And in the Android Gradle Plugin Version section choose the top most option